# PHP string splitting a pattern separated by a delimiter

Tags: php, regex, split, delimiter

I will have a php query string of the following pattern:

```
?x=a&y=b&z=c
```

with possibly more parameters after the "?". The x,y,z values will only consist of characters between aA-zZ. the a,b,c values, however, can literally be anything. They may also include & characters or = characters. Is there any way to split the x=a patterns by considering both regex and the delimiter & and place them into an associate array such as the following:

```
$values = array(x => a, y => b, z => c);
```

Edit:

I think I should clarify. x can be a value such as note. whereas a, b, c can be values such as http://yay.com/wahoo?wahoo=3&zahoo=5.

Comment: [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) should do the trick

Comment: ... or `extract($_GET)`, although this may be a little dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As scrowler wrote, [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) might do the trick, **HOWEVER**, if values "may also include & characters or = characters", how would you say if `?x=a&y=b&z=c` should be parsed as:

`$values = array(x => a, y => b, z => c);`
or rather:

`$values = array(x => a&y=b, z => c);`

or:
`$values = array(x => a&y=b&z=c);`

I guess the "&" and "=" characters will be escaped in some way, for example using [percent escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).